# Google Sheets Script : Auto check/uncheck checkboxes

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, checkbox

I'm trying to code a little script allowing me to automatically check/uncheck checkboxes in a range according to the values in another range.

I have some checkboxes in range ('C2:D24') and cells with 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' values in range ('L2:M24').
I would like that when I launch my script, the cells with value 'TRUE' in the second range automatically check corresponding checkboxes in the first range (Example : L2 value is 'TRUE', so C2 will be checked. M3 value is 'FALSE', so D3 will be unchecked).

The code I started to work on is the following, but of course it doesn't check/uncheck checkboxes but replaces them with 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' text:

```
function MAJStaff(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Staff');
  var range1 = ss.getRange('L2:M24');
  var range2 = ss.getRange('C2:D24');
  var values = range1.getValues();

  range2.setValues(values);

}
```

I guess I have to work with 'for' and 'if' functions but I don't see how to proceed.
Can you please help ?

Thanks !

The script I created replaces the checkboxes by the 'TRUE/FALSE' text but it doesn't check checkboxes as I would like it does.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to write a code, you could set in C2 (yes, over the checkbox, do not delete them)

`={L2:M24}`

The checkbox are "masks" that can illustrate what is below it

Answer (score 0):

Solving your problem via formulas is probably the easiest, but to answer your request to do this via code, you'll need to add a loop like you've heard. Here is an example loop that works.

```
function MAJStaff(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Staff');
  var range1 = ss.getRange('L2:M24');
  var range2 = ss.getRange('C2:D24');
  var values = range1.getValues();
  // You need to choose which range to define the loop dimensions. I've chosen the checkboxes range
  const numRows = range2.getNumRows();
  const numCols = range2.getNumColumns(); 

  // loop through each row (i) and column (j) of both ranges
  for (let i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      let checkbox = range2.getCell(i,j);
      let tfValue = values[i-1][j-1];
      if (tfValue == false) {
        checkbox.uncheck();
      } else if (tfValue == true) {
        checkbox.check();
      }
    }
  }
  /* understanding the loop: 
    each checkbox is the Cell at position i & j of your checkboxes range, range2
    each TRUE/FALSE value (tfValue) is the array position [i-1][j-1] (because arrays start at 0) of your range1
    if the tfValue is false, uncheck the corresponding checkbox, if it is true, check it
    this will do nothing if there is any other value (or blank) in the range1 other than TRUE or FALSE
  */ 
}
```

Do note though, that there is a base issue with your method in that you have 2 separate ranges which are not automatically the same size so there are no controls for the number of rows and columns to loop through will line up if the ranges are differently sized. For my code, I chose to use the checkboxes as the basis for the loop dimensions. Overall, it is better to think of a way to do this where the checkbox range and the T/F range has to be the exact same dimensions or are otherwise linked in some way.

Hope that helps!